# i want to query between two time ranges in a field called arrival_time

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

hi i want to query between two time ranges in a field called arrival_time 
but the query given below does not provide me with the necessary output.
Can you tell me where i am going wrong
GET /aeroplane/stop/_search?pretty

```
{
"query": {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "13:00:00",
              "lte": "15:00:00"
            }
          }
        }    
}
```

and i also tried this query
GET /aeroplane/_search?q=arrival_time:[13:00:00+TO+15:00:00]&pretty

Comment: can you share your database schema and mappings.

Comment: My index name is aeroplane, and table name is stop it has 4 columns as aeroplane_id, airport_name,arrival_time, departure_time. .The format in arrival_time is :HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  { 
     "query": 
         { 
             "range": 
               { 
                   "arrival_time": 
                      {
                          "gte": "13:00:00",
                          "lte": "15:00:00" 
                       } 
                 }
         } 
 }
```

Comment: well i tried this code but the output also posts values such as 23:24:00 which should not be included or where time is 15:54:00

Comment: it works it was just my mapping that didn't work. Thank you